# Multiple occurrences of MAX values in excel - select MAX value that has highest value in adjacent cell

Tags: excel

I have a spreadsheet with weight lifting data that has:

1. number of reps and
2. total weight lifted (for those reps)

I want to reserve a section at the bottom of the spreedsheet to record personal bests. I want to do two things in that respect:

1. find the heaviest weight that has been lifted
2. for that identified heaviest weight, I want to know how many reps the weight was lifted

I have managed to do this by using MAX and OFFSET functions but here is the problem:

- The MAX value found for the heaviest weight occurs more than once and excel just finds the first instance of this MAX value and reports back the reps that it was lifted. In my example this is 4 reps.

What I want excel to do is find the heaviest weight lifted for the most reps (i.e., if the second occurrence of the heaviest weight lifted was lifted for more reps than the first instance, I want that value reported). In my example this is 5 reps.

```
|Rep  Weight |Rep  Weight |Rep  Weight |Rep  Weight |Rep  Weight |
| 6    120   | 8    120   | 10   120   | 4     140  | 5     140  |


 Personal best
|Rep   Weight |
| 5      140  |
```

Comment: Please post sample data in tabular form as text in your question

Comment: Sure, give me as sec to figure that out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`A1:J1` Headings "Max weight" and "Rep"
`A2:J2` Values for Max weight and Rep interleaved

The heaviest weight that was lifted as an array formula:

```
{=MAX(IF(OFFSET(B2:K2;-1;0)="Max weight";B2:K2;""))}
```

The maximum reps the heaviest weight was lifted can be expressed by an array formula:

```
{=MAX(IF(OFFSET(A2:J2;-1;0)="Rep";IF(OFFSET(A2:J2;0;1)=C5;OFFSET(A2:J2;0;0);"");))}
```

The array formula is inserted by Ctrl-Shift-Enter from formula window. Curled brackets are inserted by Excel, not by a user.

[image]
Example spreadsheet: http://www.bumpclub.ee/~jyri_r/Excel/The_best_result_from_weight_lifting.xls

Comment: Thats kind of what I want.....but I need the max weight and the reps in the same row (i.e., all the data in A1:F1)

Comment: I have updated my question with a the data in tabular form to make it easier to see what I am after.

Comment: Cool, this works good as it is laid out. Can I change the range from B2:K2 to 2:2 so that I can put infinite entries in and still get the PB info out? Changed it for 'heaviest weight' and it worked but 'greatest number of reps' gave #REF!

Comment: I'd layout your data, so that it had 3 columns, first being date, second being reps, and third being max weight. Then you could put a pivot table over it and look at your data in a more meaningful way eg. look at average max weight over time, reps over time, or look at the dates you reached your max weight.

Answer (score 1):

OFFSET function is problematic when you use the whole row because you can't shift 1 cell right or left without referring to a cell that doesn't exist, hence #REF! error. Perhaps just use a large range without using the whole row, e.g. Excel 2003 has 256 columns so you can use every column but one, e.g. in C5 for the maximum weight

`=MAX(IF(B1:IV1="Weight",B2:IV2))`

and then in another cell for the associated best rep

`=MAX(IF(B1:IV1="Weight",IF(B2:IV2=C5,A2:IU2)))`

No need for OFFSET, you can just use different ranges......

both formulas confirmed with <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>

Comment: Yeah, had too little time to make things simple.